# Show table results based on count in sub query

Tags: mysql, join, count

This is really doing my head in, it be a simple query I thought.

**blog** table:

```
blog_id
blog_name
blog_copy
```

**comments** table:

```
comment_id
comment_copy
comment_by
blog_id
```

I want to show blog items where there are more than 3 comments and also order them by the volume of replies.

I tried many queries including this but it just doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    *, blog_id as BID , 
    (SELECT blog_id 
     FROM comments 
     WHERE blog = BID HAVING COUNT(*) > 3) AS t2
FROM blog
WHERE mostcomments > '3'
ORDER by mostcomments ASC
```

It says that `mostcomments` doesn't exist. I've done it other ways and it executes but counts comments on totals overall not per blog_id it's looking up

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
select b.blog_id, count(*)
from blog b
  join comments c on b.blog_id = c.blog_id
group by b.blog_id
having count(*) > 2 
order by count(*) desc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214169/2)